# Using LinearGradient for web gives error export 'requireNativeComponent' (imported as 'requireNativeComponent') was not found

Tags: react-native

I use React Native component LinearGradient for a web project.

```
<LinearGradient colors={['rgba(0,0,0,0.7)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)']}>
   <View />
</LinearGradient>
```

This produces the error

```
Using LinearGradient for web gives error export 'requireNativeComponent' (imported as 'requireNativeComponent') was not found in 'react-native-web/dist/index'
```

What could be the issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue is React Native component `<LinearGradient />` does not work for the web. One of the solutions is to use `<WebLinearGradient>` instead:

```
<WebLinearGradient colors={['rgba(0,0,0,0.7)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)']}>
   <View />
</WebLinearGradient>
```

The more dynamic and universal solution could be like this:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import WebLinearGradient from 'react-native-web-linear-gradient';

const MyGradient = Platform.OS === 'web' ? WebLinearGradient : LinearGradient;

// Use MyGradient in your component
```

Answer (score 0):

Linear Gradient is one of the property of **React Native** and react native is only a ***mobile application development platform*** . If incase you want to use gradient colors for **website** means you have to set **background color** to parent component like this ,

```css
.grad {
      background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
      }
```

```html
<div class="grad"> parent>
   <div> child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "React native is only a mobile application development platform " !== true. React Native - Learn once, write anywhere. Please, consider examples for web at https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started  
 https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation of the package, `react-native-web-linear-gradient` should be alias to `react-native-linear-gradient` when on web. Only found the documentation for webpack. So I updated my `babel.config.js`file:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  const isWeb = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_PLATFORM === 'web'; // Check the platform here
  const aliasConfig = isWeb? {'react-native-linear-gradient': 'react-native-web-linear-gradient'}: {};
  return {
    presets: [['babel-preset-expo']],
    plugins: [
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          alias: aliasConfig
        },
      ],
    ]
  };
};
```

Note that you have to preprend your expo script with `EXPO_PUBLIC_PLATFORM=web`, for instance

`EXPO_PUBLIC_PLATFORM=web npx expo start --web --reset-cache`